# How to get an NSTableView's numberOfRows at startup?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a CoreData application, with an `NSArrayController` bound to an `NSTableView`. I would like to use `scrollRowToVisible` at startup to scroll to the last row but I'm having issues. 
To obtain the number of rows, I am using `[myTable numberOfRows]`. However, I can not seam to find the proper place in code to use this at startup. After the program is running, I can click a test button and everything works.

Test button code (This does work):

```
  [myTableView scrollRowToVisible:[myTableView numberOfRows]-1];
```

I've used the following test line in several places but everywhere I try I get 0.

```
  NSLog(@"Number rows: %ld",[myTableView numberOfRows]);
```

I am using a controller vs. the `AppDelegate` for most of my code. I thought placing this in the `awakeFromNib` method of my Controller would work, but I get 0. I've placed a call from the AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to a method in my controller - still 0. 
So my question is how do I get the number of rows of my `NSTableView` at launch?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

[EDIT]----

I tried using KVO, but I am missing something. I have this in the `init` of my controller.

```
 [myArrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects"
        options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial |
                NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | 
                NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
         Context:nil];
```

and this in the code:

```
  - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                           ofObject:(id)object
                           change:(NSDictionary *)change
                           context:(void *)context
      {  NSLog(@"It worked");  }
```

"It worked" is never displayed, so something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSArrayController`s using Core Data defer fetching until the next turn of the run loop.

You could defer your own code by delaying it for an arbitrary time using a timer, `dispatch_after()`, or `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. However, this seems kind of hinky to me.

You could use Key-Value Observing to observe the array controller's `arrangedObjects` property. When that changes, unregister your observation (since you're only interested in the first change) and submit a deferred task to scroll your table view. You need to defer your scroll operation because you can't tell if the table view's binding has already been notified of the same change of `arrangedObjects` that you're responding to, so you don't know if it has added rows yet. You can defer it (without any delay interval) using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using `dispatch_after()` works, but I like the KVO idea better. I tried implementing KVO on the arrangedObjects, but something is wrong. I edited the Q above, have any thoughts?

Comment: You can't add the observation in `-init`. The array controller doesn't exist at that point and your outlet isn't connected to anything (it's `nil`). In a window controller, put it in `-windowDidLoad`. If you're not using a window controller, well, [you should be](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html), but you can do it in `-awakeFromNib` or `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. Also, you don't want to use `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial`. That calls `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` immediately which defeats the purpose in this case.

Comment: Still learning KVC/KVO, I moved it out of init and all is good - had a duh moment there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to place it in one of the view methods. Can you try it in viewDidAppear?